# jqGrid Content Type during Form Edit

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am new to jqGrid. However, successfully able to develop an application using jqGrid mainly with the help of Oleg's answers.
I load a jqGrid based on selection of drop down. the data is returned from a Web Service (asmx) file. 
The code is some thing like this

```js
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
    url: '<%= ResolveClientUrl("OfficeData.asmx/GetSCFS_RO") %>',
    editurl: '<%= ResolveClientUrl("OfficeData.asmx/SaveFPSUpdates") %>',
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: 'POST',
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }, 
    ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', dataType: 'json' },
    serializeGridData: function (postData) {
        // return null;
        if (postData.OfficeId === undefined) { postData.OfficeId = 0; }
        else {
            postData.OfficeId = officeId;
        }
        return JSON.stringify(postData);
    }, 
    jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, root: "d.rows", page: "d.page",
        total: "d.total", records: "d.records" },
    colNames: ['FPSCode',  'Owner Name ', 'Licese_No', 'ShopAddress', 'Village',
        'License Valid From', 'Valid To','FPS Type','WholeSalerName',  'Mobile'],
    colModel: [{ name: 'FPSCode', index: 'FPSCode', width: 60, align: 'left',
        editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, 
        editoptions:{ 
            dataInit: function(element) { 
                $(element).attr("readonly", "readonly"); 
            } 
        }
    },
    ......
```

Firebug shows the following Post header

**Response Headers**

```
......
Content-Type      application/json; charset=utf-8
Date              Tue, 20 Nov 2012 14:20:34 GMT
Server            ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version  4.0.30319
```

**Request Headers**

```
Accept            application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding   gzip, deflate
Accept-Language   en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control     no-cache
Connection        keep-alive
Content-Length    105
..........
```

As expected the response I get is JSON object.

However the Form submit always sends `Content-Type` as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`

**Response Headers**

```
Cache-Control     private, max-age=0
Connection        Close
Content-Length    95
Content-Type      text/xml; charset=utf-8
Date              Tue, 20 Nov 2012 14:20:46 GMT
Server            ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
```

**Request Headers**

```
Accept            */*
Accept-Encoding   gzip, deflate
Accept-Language   en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control     no-cache
Connection        keep-alive
Content-Length    254
Content-Type      application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie            ASP.NET_SessionId=utts2wlhdto4xhae34fzqkt4
Host              localhost:18017
Pragma            no-cache
Referer           Account/FPSUpdate.aspx
User-Agent        Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
X-Requested-With  XMLHttpRequest
X-AspNet-Version  4.0.30319
```

As suggested at Stackoverflow I have used

```js
ajaxEditOptions:  { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', dataType: 'json' } ,
```

I tried even to use `ajaxEditoptions` at

```js
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.edit, {
    ajaxEditOptions:  { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', dataType: 'json' },
    ...
});
```

However there is no change in the `Content-Type`.
As a consequence I always get an XML response from the server for the Update. The output from the server is

```xml
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Data Saved</string>
```

I am unable to fix the Mime type to JSON. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I am glad, that my old answers could help you.

The usage of `ajaxEditOptions` as the option of jqGrid is really incorrect. It's option of [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties) and so you have to include it as property in the `prmEdit` and `prmAdd` option of [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#definition) or to use

```js
$.extend($.jgrid.edit, {
    ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: "application/json" }
});
```

You wrote that you tried to use very close option. I recommend you to verify it one more time. To be sure that the line will be executed you can include it somewhere at the beginning of your JavaScript script.

I personally use

```js
$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
    ajaxRowOptions: { contentType: "application/json", async: true },
    ajaxSelectOptions: { contentType: "application/json", dataType: "JSON" },
    ...
});
$.extend($.jgrid.edit, {
    ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
    recreateForm: true,
    serializeEditData: function(postData) {
        return JSON.stringify(postData);
    },
    ....
});
$.extend($.jgrid.del, {
    ajaxDelOptions: { contentType: "application/json" }
    ...
});
```

and everything works as expected: one can see `Content-Type: application/json` in the HTTP header of the corresponding requests.

**UPDATED**: I think that the origin of the strange behavior of jqGrid is small bug which I reported to trirand [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/one-need-use-deep-recursive-jquery-extend-in-grid-formedit-js/#p27764). You can make corresponding modification yourself in your copy of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` or hold the rule: if you define some non-scalar (object) options in `$.jgrid.edit` like `ajaxEditOptions` you should not use the options in `navGrid`. If you would fix the code of jqGrid as I described in [the bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/one-need-use-deep-recursive-jquery-extend-in-grid-formedit-js/#p27764) the restriction will not more exist.

**UPDATED 2**: The bug is already fixed (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/65ce3a1d61b14f0131dc23856ca76da0e56cc3af)) in the main code on the github. So the next version of jqGrid (higher as 4.4.1) should not have the described problem.

Comment: thanks, with out your answers and codes I could not have done it. BTW I always do a google like JQGrid <my problem> Oleg.   Just now could identify the problem. In my code there is a navGrid method which is .jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { edit: true, add: false, del: false, refresh: true, search: true },
         {            
         closeAfterEdit:false});        
               });  I feel this is overriding the jQuery.jgrid.edit where the ajaxEditOptions is written.  Because the moment I put ajaxEditOptions in the navGrid method it is sending a right mime. What's your opinion?

Comment: You can use `$.extend($.jgrid.edit, {ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: "application/json" }});` or you can use `.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { edit: true, add: false, del: false, refresh: true, search: true }, { closeAfterEdit:false, ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: "application/json" }});`. **The both ways should work**. If it will do not work you can post me URL with the demo which reproduce the problem. Please use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` in the demo.

Comment: Either of them should work. But what happens if one uses both (inadvertently)  with navGrid having just  .jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { edit: true, add: false, del: false, refresh: true, search: true }, { closeAfterEdit:false and $.extend having  ajaxEditOptions. In my case it was sending a mime type text/xml and the moment I removed ajaxEditOptions in the $.extend and put it navGid  method it started sending right mime. Thanks again Oleg for your time.

Comment: @Dibs: I think I know the reason of the problem. It's bug in [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.formedit.js#L303-L347) of code `editGridRow`. It uses [jQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/#jQuery-extend1) **without** `deep` option. To fix the problem one need change `p = $.extend({...}, $.jgrid.edit, p || {});` at the beginning of the code `editGridRow` to `p = $.extend(true, {...}, $.jgrid.edit, p || {});`. You can test this in your copy of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`. I will report the bug to trirand later.

Comment: @Dibs: I posted the bug report [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/one-need-use-deep-recursive-jquery-extend-in-grid-formedit-js/#p27764)

Comment: Thanks..would you explain a bit what is 'without deep option'. It is really amazing that you pin point problems with such an ease.

Comment: @Dibs: [$.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/#jQuery-extend1) has two form of usage: 1) `jQuery.extend( target [, object1] [, objectN] )` 2) `jQuery.extend( [deep], target, object1 [, objectN] )`. The first form don't make **recursive** combination of `target`, `object1`, `object1`, ... `objectN`. In your case if `ajaxEditOptions` defined in any for as the parameter of `navGrid` it *overwrite* (instead of combining) any settings of `ajaxEditOptions` from `$.jgrid.edit`.

Comment: Thanks. I think Jquey documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)  also explain the deep extension. Now I understand it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Dibs: How you can see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/65ce3a1d61b14f0131dc23856ca76da0e56cc3af) the bug is fixed.